# Lightning styling of multi-picklist in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, slds

was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for how to do styling of a multi-picklist in a lightning manner within a visualforce page?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Surgery__c.FieldSets[fixed]}" var="field">
    <div class=".slds-dueling-list">
        <!-- Method 1 -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!fs[field]}" /> 

        <!-- Method 2 -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!fs[field]}" styleClass="slds-input"/>

        <!-- Method 3 -->
        <apex:selectList multiselect="true" styleClass="slds-input">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fs[field]}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

If anyone has any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong (I'm pretty sure I'm doing method 3 incorrectly but I'm not sure how to fix it)

All of the methods above don't produce anything that's particularly appealing to look at

[image: Image of what the different methods look like]

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried SLDS Dueling Picklist?

Check this out: [SLDS Dueling Picklist](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dueling-picklist/)

Markup:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="slds-dueling-list">
    <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="drag-live-region" aria-live="assertive">
    </div>
    <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="option-drag-label">
        Press space bar when on an item, to move it within the list. CMD plus left and right arrow keys, to move items between lists.
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
        <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-7">
            First Category
        </span>
        <div class="slds-dueling-list__options" role="application">
            <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-7" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 1">
                                Option 1
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 2">
                                Option 2
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 3">
                            Option 3
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 6">
                            Option 6
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection to Second Category">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#right">
                </use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection to Second Category
            </span>
        </button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection to First Category">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#left">
                </use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">
                Move Selection to First Category
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
        <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-8">
            Second Category
        </span>
        <div class="slds-dueling-list__options" role="application">
            <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-8" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
                        <span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 4">
                            Option 4
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 5">
                                Option 5</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection Up">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#up">
                </use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection Up</span>
        </button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection Down">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down">
                </use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">
                Move Selection Down
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace `<svg><svg/>` with desired icons(slds-icon utility-sprite right,left,up,down).
Iterate the `<li>` with your data.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I did try that, but it seems that I have to know how many elements are present first? Or more like I since I'm pulling it from a fieldset I don't know how to iterate through all the elements and display them like that

Comment: Try using this (my) component via lightning out: https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect